# Zend Framework Inspect Controller class for docblock tags

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, controller, instance

I wanted to implement an Authorization FrontController Plugin based on Annotations just like ASP.NET Mvc.
I thought I could write a front controller plugin and add the Authorization check into one of the Hooks provided by Zend Framework. Example:

```
class My_Controller_Plugin_Authorize extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){
        ...
        if($user_is_not_loggedin){
             goSomeWhereElse();
        }
    }
}

class MyFancyController extends Zend_Controller_Action{

   /**
    * @Authorize
    */
    public function secretAction(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I need to inspect docblocks in the actual requested controller to find out if the action the user is heading to requires to be authorized or not.
And it turned out to be not so simple: the Request Object is the only resource that gets passed into the Hooks.

I thought I could build the controller's class name by doing controllerName + "Controller" but the class doesn't get autoloaded and so it's not found and the code crushes.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I actually found a solution digging in the ZendFramework classes:
     $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
     $dispatcher = $frontController->getDispatcher();
     $controllerClass = $dispatcher->getControllerClass($request);
     $dispatcher->loadClass($controllerClass);
     $annotation = new Zend_Reflection_Docblock(new Zend_Reflection_Class($controllerClass));

Looks like it works now, but I don't know anything about performance

Comment: Reflection is slow, but 'slow' is relative. Benchmark to see if this is going to cause you problems and if so, then you can consider caching.

Answer (score 0):

As you note in your comment to your question, the dispatcher has access to the actual controller *instance* - as opposed to just the controller *name*.

Another place that has access to the controller instance is an [action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html), which has access to the controller instance. So perhaps an action helper with a `preDispatch()` hook that performs the reflection-based docblock introspection? Probably some performance hit, as reflection is considered slow.

But, in general, this sounds like you want access-control, which is usually handled using `Zend_Acl` and then writing a controller plugin that utilizes that ACL object. Unless you *really* need to do reflection-based inspection of docblock annotations for your ACL, I'd go with the the ACL/plugin approach.

Answer (score 0):

This si my solution. The @Authorize annotation works either on the top of the class or on the top of the single methods.
Obviously can be extended to check with ACL.

```
<?php
class Ant_Controller_Plugin_Authorize extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $dispatcher = $frontController->getDispatcher();
        $controllerClass = $dispatcher->getControllerClass($request);
        $dispatcher->loadClass($controllerClass);
        $reflectionClass = new Zend_Reflection_Class($controllerClass);
        $reflectionMethod = $reflectionClass->getMethod($dispatcher->getActionMethod($request));
        try {
            $authClass = $reflectionClass->getDocblock()->hasTag("Authorize");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $authClass = false;
        }
        try{
            $authMethod = $reflectionMethod->getDocblock()->hasTag("Authorize");
        }catch (Exception $e){
            $authMethod = false;
        }

        if($authClass || $authMethod){
            if(!Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()){
                $request->setActionName("login")->setControllerName("Accounts");
                $request->setDispatched(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then in the application.ini

```
resources.frontController.plugins.Authorize = "Ant_Controller_Plugin_Authorize"
```